# MarkLogic Data Hub Framework Quick Start Hub - Error "unsupported auth scheme: [Basic realm=public]" when connecting to a remote Instance

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am testing out the ML DHF Quickstart Hub from my workstation and can connect fine to a local instance of MarkLogic. But when I create a new environment *gradle-DEV.properties* file and try to connect to a remote MarkLogic cluster I get the error:

> unsupported auth scheme: [Basic realm=public]

Checking the logs on the remote instance I do see that the login attempts have authenticated.

Are there specific MarkLogic Configurations required by the Data Hub Framework that I might be missing?

Comment: Dan, which version of the Data Hub Quickstart are you using? And which version of MarkLogic?

Comment: Quickstart 2.0.1 running on windows desktop, connecting to MarkLogic 9.0.3 on RHEL7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dan,

That error means that your App-Services appserver on your DEV MarkLogic instance is set to `basic` authentication.

You need to make QuickStart aware of this so that it can authenticate properly. Simply add this to your gradle-DEV.properties:

`mlAppServicesAuthentication=basic`

Then refresh the browser on QuickStart and try again. Should work with that property set.

-Paxton

Comment: Also, I added a new github issue asking for a better error message: https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-data-hub/issues/593. We can do a better job of helping you fix this when we detect it.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the benefit of others: in DHF 5.1.0, refreshing the browser didn't help, but restarting QuickStart after updating the properties file worked.