# not able to deploy Marklogic Modules through Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I am trying to build CI in jenkins for marklogic but in Deploy step i am getting below error

Execution failed for task ':ml-modules:mlDeployApp'.

> unsupported auth scheme: [Basic realm=public]

How to resolve this issue. I have tried different auth scheme like basic, application level etc

Comment: Have you tried digest? Also, this page may help https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Debugging-module-loading

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47579188/14419